# Android Studio failed to convert OK into a drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-appwidget

Have the following log:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Color value 'OK' must start with #
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getColor(ResourceHelper.java:87)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:356)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:238)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:207)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
    at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:134)
    at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$53(RenderTask.java:659)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and the following error message

```
failed to convert OK into a drawable
The graphics preview in the layout may not be accurate
Paint setShadowLayer is not supported
```

I've booted up Android Studio and have a couple of views laid out on the XML; except they do not show up on the preview! I can only assume this means that android studio is not drawing whatever is on the XML; any explanation as to why? What can I do so that android studio 'draws' it?

Comment: Show you code where you call that `OK`

Comment: hi
it was a textinput layout wrapper that I simply deleted so no more rendering problems

Comment: Please check if your color code starts with # or not like #FFFFFF.